# ¿Cómo cambiar en R una columna de fechas numéricas de un fichero excel por sus correpondientes días de la semana?

Tags: r

Tengo que trabajar con un fichero excel para analizar las distintas variables del mismo, pero necesito hacer gráficas empleando en el eje de abscisas los días de la semana (Lunes, Martes, Miércoles..) y la columna de la variable fecha está dada en formato numérico (03/08/20..).
He encontrado un comando que me cambia una fecha concreta por su día correpondiente de la semana:
format(fecha, "%A")
Pero necesito cambiar todas las fechas y no puedo hacerlo una a una ya que tengo Agosto y Septiembre enteros.
He pensando crear una función que me lleve a cabo la orden format en toda la columna. Pero no lo consigo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrias hacer es agregar una columna nueva (una nueva variable) con el nombre de los dias de la semana, de la siguiente forma:

- Supongamos que tu dataframe (tu tabla de excel) se llama **fichero**.
- Llamaremos **fecha** a la variable de tu dataframe que contiene las fechas.
- Usare la funcion **wday** del paquete **lubridate**; lo que hace esta funcion es extraer el dia de la semana de un objeto DATE o POSIXct y te da la posiblidad de etiquetarlo con el nombre del dia.
- Llamemos **dias** a la nueva variable que crearemos

```
install.packages("lubridate")
library("lubridate")

#ahora crearemos la nueva variable dias
fichero$dias <- wday(fichero$fecha, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
```

De esta forma se ha creado una nueva columna con los nombres de los dias.

El argumento `abbr = FALSE` cuando se lo pone FALSE hace que el nombre del dia no sea abreviado, es decir, si lo quieres puedes borrar dicho argumento del codigo y en vez de tener por ejemplo **jueves** en tu columna nueva, lo tendras abreviado como **jue**.